# "invalid form key. please refresh the page" - cannot login to admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, session, form-key

I regularly visit my site to make sure its working and noticed that images for products were not appearing, thinking it was a problem with indexing  cache I tried to login to the admin panel and received the error:

"invalid form key. please refresh the page"

[image: or]

Other symptoms are customers could not add products to cart and extremely slow performance.

There are no errors in the logs (/var/logs)

**What additional steps should I perform to resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am posting the question / answer because I couldn't find anything relevant.

The issue was that the drive on which my magento installation resides was full. I freed up some room, clear the /var/session and /var/cache and everything went back to normal.

Comment: **Warning:** deleting `var/session` will log out everybody and clear all guest carts. See here for a solution that only removes old sessions: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/58167/243

Comment: @fschmengler yes but do you really want to take a chance with sessions that werent properly created to begin with? When I checked the /var/session there were all kinds of 0kb files which is not normal.

Comment: Absolutely a first thing to check. Been racking my head on this for hours. Thanks!

Comment: For me it was disk space. I found out after trying to git pull, as it failed with disk space related error.

Comment: @SR_Magento Sir I was removed cache folder and session folder so many time  it's works only for some time after some time there is an same issue

Comment: @AmareshTiwari how much free disk space do you have? Have you reset the permissions for those folders after deletion?

Comment: yes sir  I just set the permission 777 for cache and session and remove that but after 5 min same issues will come what should I do now

Comment: Now solved after delete cache and session folder , change the password also now it works fine

Comment: that is because of  magento is unable to save session data on disk

Answer (score 57):

It also happens if the cookie domain in *System > Configuration > Web > Cookies* is different from the actual site domain.

To remove the setting without access to the admin panel:

1. use the following SQL query on the MySQL console or in a client like phpMyAdmin:

   ```
   DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';
   ```
2. clear the cache. If you are using the default file based cache backend, delete all directories below `var/cache`.

Then as soon as you can log in again, set the correct cookie domain for each website or store (Example: `.example.com` for example.com, www.example.com and all other subdomains)

If you are using [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net/) (and you should!), the same can be accomplished with:

```
n98-magerun config:delete web/cookie/cookie_domain
n98-magerun cache:clean config
```

Comment: Hi @fschmengler, please add more details on how to check this setting from phpmyadmin, because user is not able to login to admin panel and some developers who are new to Magento development don't know where to check such settings in database. Sorry, but just for help of new members :)

Comment: @MohitKumarArora you are right, I updated the answer

Comment: Now I have upvoted. :)

Comment: n98 way works fantastic. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @FabianSchmengler, I checked the core_config_data and it's the correct value for my site. Do I still need to go through all the steps you provided? Would your approach still work in this case?

Comment: in my case it was also switching session storage in `app/etc/local.xml` file to files instead of memcache:     
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[C:\magento 1.9.31\tmp\session]]></session_save_path>

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 solutions:

1. Use these commands in phpmyadmin

   DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';

   DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_path';

Now Try to login.

2.Delete everything in var folder and then check if it works.

3.Replace the .htaccess file with sample .htaccess file and then try to login the admin.

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem seems to be because I've created the admin user using n98-magerun with an user that cannot write on magentofolder/var and used the fallback folder /tmp/magento instead.

I just deleted my admin user and executed a `sudo -iu OTHERUSER`(user that owns the magento folder) and ran `n98-magerun admin:user:create` again to create my user.

---

UPDATE: In another case, the admin url has being visited without **www.** syntax, and the cookie settings was using www. Just putting the www. in the admin url solved the problem. ;)

Comment: Shouldn't this be `admin:user:create`?

Comment: @sr9yar nope - that's Magento2 - this is M1

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases of the cookie configuration that could be obstructing the session functionality.

The domain of the cookie does not match, or the protocol (ssl or not) here is what it looks a request where the cookie is set as "secure" but its not using an http ssl url:

[image]

to fix them both you just have to run following:

```
    DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_secure';
    DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```

and then clear the cache. for file based cache:

```
    rm -Rf var/cache/mage--*
```

for redis:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible, somewhat obvious, problem to check first: if your site uses SSL, make sure you're not using the http protocol for your admin page; you should be using **https**. e.g. https://example.com/admin

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above step of clearing cache, i also had to follow the below article and set the session data information in correct path by following the below steps

Ref article

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123081/failed-to-write-session-data-magento

I fixed it by changing the session.save_path to place it in the VM.

Change the file app/etc/local.xml

replaced with below

Then it started working. Also at times you cannot really tell the issue, thus it is important you enable error logging. Enable this by referring to following article

https://www.thecreativedev.com/how-to-enable-system-log-and-errorswarning-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Clear cookies and cache. Open admin panel in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by

1.Clear browsing data > ctrl+shift+del

2.Clear cookie settings "Sites that should never use cookies" > chrome://settings/cookies

"invalid form key" (chrome browser)

Answer (score 0):

Hi could something explain the solution to this problem without using it language. Honestly you might aswel be speaking a different language. We can all do that about things we know about but it doesn't help people with the problem, just causes further confusion.

Answer (score -3):

This is known issue generally comes after applying patch SUPEE-7405 included in Magento 1.9.2.3 release. It can be solved by adding below code in file -  app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php

```
public function validateFormKey()
{
    if (!($formKey = $_REQUEST['form_key']) || $formKey != $this->getFormKey()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This file might not exist in your repository so copy it from `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php` and paste it in `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php` After that add above function in file because it may be missing in core file.

Also clear your browser cache and cookies. Clear all files in Magento `var/cache` and `var/session` folders contents. Then login to your admin panel.

Comment: Ermm..wouldn't a better solution be to add the form key block output to the overridden adminhtml template?  (That way the CSRF protection will work as intended).

Comment: One should never edit core files.