# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page while creating new users in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, error, form-key, create-account

> Whenever adding new users or editing, updating the products in
>   frontend shows the error Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

***I increased the value of input_max_var but still it showing the error often. Is I need to increase the values for max_input_time and max_execution_time too? Between the site is slow. Will the slow loading cause such issues? ***

*It also displaying the alert messages lately after saving the product or creating users.*

*What is the solution?*

*Kindly help me.*

Comment: The issue was that the drive on magento installation resides was full.  clear the /var/session and /var/cache and everything went back to normal.

Comment: can you check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58166/cleaning-up-magento-installation-which-files-folders-can-be-deleted/

Comment: Thank you, Divya. I will check out now.

Comment: @divyasekar Can you answer this one ->https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290595/variable-button-shadow-active-is-undefined-while-running-deploy-static-content

Comment: @divyasekar Can I get you mail id or skype? Will be helpful for me to ping you if I have any doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding reference container content in the layout.xml file.

Comment: regarding to this screenshot https://prnt.sc/papfqq  you have use any custom discount amount  and check your sales_order page both frontend and backend  then let me know there also order total show as '0'

Comment: Are you override any Magento sales order totals block